# how to fire window.resize only once?

Tags: javascript, css

Here is my code;

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 760) {
    $('.sidebar-left').one().css("display", "block")
  } else if ($(window).width() <= 760) {
    $('.sidebar-left').one().css("display", "none")

  }

});

var m = $(".menu");

m.addClass('fa-bars');

m.on('click', function() {
  if (m.hasClass('fa-bars')) {
    m
      .removeClass('fa-bars')
      .addClass('fa-times');
    $(".sidebar-left").css("display", "block")
  } else {
    m
      .removeClass('fa-times')
      .addClass('fa-bars');
    $(".sidebar-left").css("display", "none")

  }
});
```

```css
.sidebar-left {
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu.fa {
  display: none;
}
@media handheld,
screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .sidebar-left {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .menu.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu fa"></div>
<div class="sidebar-left"></div>
```

And a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/t8Ov50mgEERLUw1gQqkk?p=preview). (may be easier to test here)

So it's just a simple menu. The issue I have is that currently the resize event will run every time the page is resized, so if I have the menu displayed under 760 pixels it will automatically disappear on resize if I have it opened.

If I take the javascript resize function out completely and leave it to the css, the problem is if I open and close the menu in a smaller window, the display will be set to none when I make the window larger again.

I've tried a few other things, but can't seem to think of a way of doing this. The aim is to just to replicate what the $(window).resize function is doing currently, but for that event to fire only once the window has resized past the points.

Hope the problem is explained clearly.

Thanks

Comment: rather than, running the function once: would it not be better to run the function but check if the menu is open? and then when you close the menu, run the resize code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jQuery's [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method, which gets activated exactly once:

```
$(window).one('resize', function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 760) {
    $('.sidebar-left').one().css("display", "block")
  } else if ($(window).width() <= 760) {
    $('.sidebar-left').one().css("display", "none")

  }

});
```

This will solve your question as asked, but i would actually recommend not disabling the resize event and just handling it better, i.e. checking whether it is proper to open/close the sidebar.

Comment: Hi - when you use the .one method if you make the screen a smaller size, open and close the menu and then make the screen larger again the menu is set to `display:none`

Comment: @lolio Yes, that is how it is intended to work. See the paragraph at the end where i point out caveats and recommendations.

Comment: is it possible to elaborate a little more? I have tried `if($(window).width() >= 760 && $('.sidebar-left').css("display", "none")){
    $('.sidebar-left').one().css("display", "block")
}` (and the reverse) but still have problems mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plugin I made, with a `resize begin` handler, a `resize end` handler and of course an `on resize` handler.

```
(function() {
var resizeEventHandler = function(resizeTarget, _maxResizeWaitTime, onResizeBeginCB, onResizeEndCB, onResizeCB) {
    if(resizeTarget){
        var resizeTimer = null;
        var resizeBegun = false;
        var maxResizeWaitTime = _maxResizeWaitTime || 500;

        resizeTarget.addEventListener('resize', function() {
            if (!resizeBegun) {
                if(onResizeBeginCB){
                    onResizeBeginCB();
                }
                resizeBegun = true;
            }

            if(onResizeCB){
                onResizeCB();
            }

            clearTimeout(resizeTimer);

            resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                if(onResizeEndCB){
                    onResizeEndCB();
                }
                resizeBegun = false;
            }, maxResizeWaitTime);
        });

    }else{
        console.error('No resizeTarget specified!');
    }
};

this.resizeEventHandler = resizeEventHandler;

}).call(this);
```

Call it like this:

```
function onResizeBegin() {
    $("body").append('onResizeBegin<br/>')
}

function onResizeEnd() {
    $("body").append('onResizeEnd<br/>')
}

function onResize() {
    $("body").append('onResize<br/>')
}

var resizeEventHandler1 = new resizeEventHandler(window, 500, onResizeBegin, onResizeEnd, onResize);
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sv52m1y2/3/